# Mod_ReWrite script from apache 1.3 doesn't work in 2.2

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache-1.3

I had been using the following script for friendly urls and it is working fin in apache 1.3. We just upgraded to apache 2.2.17 and it doesnt seem to be working anymore.

Is there something that needs to be tweaked to work in 2.2?

```
 mysite.com/products?BRAND=ADIDAS&VENDORCODE=581 (ORIGINAL URL)
 mysite.com/products/ADIDAS/581 (FRIENDLY URL)



Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^(.*/)?products/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1/products?BRAND=$2&VENDORCODE=$3 [PT,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1/products?BRAND=$2&VENDORCODE=$3&offset=$4 [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*/)?DeptItems/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1/DeptItems?BRAND=$2&catCode=$3 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?DeptItems/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1/DeptItems?BRAND=$2&catCode=$3&offset=$4 [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*/)?itemdetail/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/itemdetail?BRAND=$2&desc1=$3 [PT,L]
```

Comment: is module mod_rewrite is still enabled?

Comment: on linux `# a2enmod rewrite` dont know how it's on windows

Comment: What exactly is happening? I just tested the rules, and it seems OK. I changed the `PT` on the first rule to `R` and `/products/ADIDAS/581` redirected to `/products?BRAND=ADIDAS&VENDORCODE=58`.  Do you have another module running that you passing the URLs to, like `mod_jk`?

Comment: Yes, I have apache running in front of tomcat.  Apache passes the requests on to tomcat.  if is use /products?BRAND=ADIDAS&VENDORCODE=581 it will hit the servlet correctly it just isn't working with the re_writes.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteEngine On` needs to be on its own line. Its not an argument to `Options`.

Comment: sorry, that was actually a formatting issue when i posted the code.  It is on its own line on the server

Answer (score -1):

For Apache2.2

In your **httpd.conf** file you must set **AllowOverride All**